# dependency property object doesn't update

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, object, dependency-properties

Good day. I have problem with DependencyProperty updating.Why It doesn't update after clicking button. Can you help me?

*WpfApplication5.MainWindow*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;


namespace WpfApplication5
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    TestData TD = new TestData();
    SomeStructure SS = new SomeStructure();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        SS.Name = "OIL";
        TD.Name = "GOLD";
        TD.CompanyName=SS;
        this.DataContext = TD;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SS.Name = "OIL2";
        TD.CompanyName=SS;
    }
}
public class ConvertValue : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
public class SomeStructure
{
    public int Option { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class TestData : DependencyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Assettyp { get; set; }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CompanyNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CompanyName", typeof(SomeStructure), typeof(TestData), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(SomeStructure), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public SomeStructure CompanyName
    {
        get { return (SomeStructure)this.GetValue(CompanyNameProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(CompanyNameProperty, value); }
    }
}
}
```

*xaml code*

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ConvertValue x:Key="SellBuy"></local:ConvertValue>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Label x:Name="TestLabel" Width="120" Height="25" Content="{Binding CompanyName,Converter={StaticResource SellBuy}}"></Label>
    <Button Content="Button" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="340,143,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" Click="button1_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

*It seems that UI doesn't know that content is updated?*

Comment: What is the purpose of your Converter?

Comment: The purpose of the converter is to change size of each character.

Comment: But i think it's not the main problem.

Comment: In addition to the answer given by Rob van Daal, it is also worth to note that you should not use dependency properties in view models. Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface instead.

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged is slower than the DependencyProperty.

Comment: I seriously doubt that. Who told you so?

Comment: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/62158/DependencyProperties-or-INotifyPropertyChanged)

Comment: And that scenario makes sense for you? Which update rates of your view model properties do you expect to have? All this is just premature optimization. You are effectivly ruining your application architecture for a few imagined milliseconds. That guy is giving you a really bad advice. You may also carefully read the comments on the article to get a better picture.

Comment: You have a world of pain ahead of you if you stick to using depobjects as your base class for your viewmodels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no new instance assigned to TD.CompanyName, so there will be no notification.